# Mint pc boots to no video ... or usb power. What's going on?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, usb, video

This is a problem that's truly got me stumped, and I've been doing support for several decades.

I've set up my in-laws with a pc running Linux Mint 13 (so that they don't screw it up like they would a Windows pc). Except for a few issues it's been a great success! The pc is a hand-me-down Medion (with some NVidia video card) that's always been rock solid.

Today, they called me up saying there's no display, and sure enough -- after the splash screen the display actually turns off (as in, "the green light goes yellow"), and I can't even switch to a TTY to log in and check dmesg -- because the keyboard and mouse have no power! What?! They work just fine in the BIOS and have power through much of the boot process. I haven't yet tested with a PS/2 keyboard and mouse (I have some, but I didn't have them on hand at the time). Booting with no USB peripherals makes no difference: the display goes off, and plugging in a mouse doesn't power it up.

How can I diagnose this problem? What could possibly turn off power to USB and VGA after (or during) booting?

PS. When I say that the splash screen shows up, that's an approximation. It's never been able to show anything else than a couple of white bars across the display, but then the desktop comes up just fine in full resolution. I just never bothered to fix the splash screen.

Comment: Can they get to the BIOS?

Comment: I can access the BIOS just fine (maybe I was unclear about that), and I've checked all the settings. I am quite certain that my in-laws have _not_ accessed/changed it, though!

Comment: Is the CDROM/USB bootaable from the BIOS?

Comment: is the hardware arch compatible fully with the dist? i would put a password on the BIOS

Comment: Yes they both are (but I didn't have anything bootable with me at the time).

Comment: Give them Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: If a CDROM/USB boot and you see the installer on the live disk, the monitor and card are fine.  If you boot a CDROM/USB and the screen is still black, replace the monitor, and try again.  If still black replace the Graphics card.

Comment: eyoung, thank you for the suggestions, but I doubt their effectivevess. The equipment must be fine since BIOS works, unless it suddenly developed a dislike of full resolution (doesn't explain USB power).
unixmiah, the BIOS but is ruled out (I could lock it though). My goal is to revive the pc+system, avoid a re-install or new purchase.

Comment: Whilest I agree with the method, there is no way to test the GPU unless you use the method I describe.  The BIOS VGA works because it is using the VESA fallback standard.  In order to test the card in Operating Mode, you must boot any live disk.  Now do you understand my "effectiveness?"  This is Hardware troubleshooting, ie, the VGA port stopped working when switching from VESA to native etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the next few boots identified the problem. There were increasing problems reading the memory, and eventually the video never even turned on for the bios power-on self test.
I opened up the case -- the graphics card and AGP slot have a scorch mark covering 2-3 connectors. The card is busted, probably ditto for the main board.